# Promise all with inner function to be executed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to retrieve different HTML body at once and as soon as all results are available work with that content.

My callback solution which works looks like this (probably only relevant to read if the idea is not clear, otherwise skip ;)):

```
const request = require('request')

const argLength = process.argv.length
const result_array = []
let counter = 0

function executeRequest () {
  for (start = 2; start <= argLength - 1; start++) {
    const copy = start

    function callback (error, res, body) {
      const startCopy = copy
      if (error) {
        console.log('error')
        return
      }
      result_array[startCopy - 2] = body.toString().length
      counter++
      if (counter === argLength - 2) {
        console.log(result_array)
      }
    }

    request(process.argv[start], callback)
  }
}

executeRequest()
```

**Now I try to make it running with Promises like this:**

```
const httpRequest = require('request')
const argumentLength = process.argv.length

function fillURLArray () {
  resultArray = []
  for (start = 2; start < argumentLength; start++) {
    resultArray[start - 2] = process.argv[start]
  }
  return resultArray
}

const urls = fillURLArray()

let counter = 0

function readHttp () {
  const resultArray = []
  Promise.all(urls.map(url => httpRequest(url, (error, res, body) => {
    console.log(body.toString())
    resultArray[counter++] = body.toString()
  }))).then(value => {
    console.log('promise counter: ' + counter++)
    console.log(resultArray)
    console.log('called')
  })
}

readHttp()
```

I tried already several attempts with different promise chains but every time I get either not a result or just an empty array. So obviously the `.then()` function is called before the array is actually filled (at least I guess so since `console.log(body.toString())` appears to print the content some time later)

Any idea how to solve this with promises?

Thank you

Comment: npm request does not return promises so array you pass to Promise.all() is not array of promises. Use one of the request libraries that includes promises https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` is not returning promise object so have created a method that return promise object on which you do `Promise.all`.

```
function requestPromise(url){
  return new Promise((resovle,reject) => {
     httpRequest(url, (error, res, body) => {
      if(err){
         reject(err);
      }
      resolve(body.toString());
  });
  });
}


function readHttp () {
  const resultArray = []
  Promise.all(urls.map(url => requestPromise(url))).then(values => {
    console.log("counter => ",values.length);
    resultArray = resultArray.concat(values);
    console.log("values=> ",values);
    console.log("resultArray=> ",resultArray);
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this already. The problem here is that the returned array has only one entry.  But it should has as much as urls are delivered.

Comment: @AnnaKlein I think charlietfl has answer your question. `request` is not returning promise object. So go with this npm module - https://github.com/request/request-promise to handle promise wtih request

Answer (score 1):

`httpRequest` does not return a promise so you have to make one yourself, also  your `resultArray` is not necessary:

```
 const makeRequest = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => httpRequest(url, (error, res) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(res)));

 Promise.all(urls.map(makeRequest))
   .then(result => {         
     console.log(result.map(res => res.body.toString()));
     console.log('called');
   });
```